# How to plot hierarchical time series in Rmarkdown shinny

Tags: plot, shiny, time-series, r-markdown

I wish to plot hierarchical time series which are contained inside a list as per the code bellow:
libraries and data creation

```
title: "prueba shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dygraphs)
library(tseries)

df <- data.frame(date = c(as.yearmon(2018,1),as.yearmon(2018,1),as.yearmon(2018,2),as.yearmon(2018,2),
                          as.yearmon(2018,1),as.yearmon(2018,1),as.yearmon(2018,2),as.yearmon(2018,2)),                sales = c(1,2,3,4),
                 cat_I = c("drink","drink","food","food","drink","drink","food","food"),
                 cat_II = c("cola","fanta","tomatoes","bananas","cola","fanta","tomatoes","bananas"))

cat <- data.frame(I = c("drink","drink","food","food"),
                  II = c("cola","fanta","tomatoes","bananas"))
```

creaition of individual time series for each end product (ts):

```
ts <- list()
for(s in unique(cat$II)){
  aux <- df %>%  filter(cat_II==s) %>%  
    as.data.frame()
  ts[[s]] <- ts(aux$sales,start=c(2018,1),frequency = 12)
}
```

creation of a hierarchical list for endpoint products (ts_I_II) and grouped by categories

```
aux <- with(cat,split(II,I))
ts_I_II <-  lapply(aux, function(x) ts[x])

catI_sales <- list()
for (s in unique(cat$I)){
  catI_sales[[s]] <- do.call(cbind,ts_I_II[[s]])
}
```

desired plots:
1 - first plot contains all time series inside a category

```
aux <- do.call(cbind,ts_I_II$drink)
dygraph(aux, main = "sales by cat_II") %>% dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Set2"))
```

2 - second plot is the end product time series

```
dygraph(ts_I_II$drink$cola, main = "sales by cat_II") %>% dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Set2"))
```

I wish to create both plots by selecting the categories from a selectInput. I tried something like this without success:

```
selectInput("I", label = "category_I:",
           choices = unique(cat$I), selected = cat$I[1])
selectInput("II", label = "II", choices = unique(cat$II))

plotOutput(outputId = "dy")

data <- reactive({
  ts_I_II$input$II})

output$dy <- renderPlot({
   dygraph(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectInput("II", label = "category_II:",
           choices = names(ts))


dygraphs::renderDygraph({
  dygraph(ts[[input$II]])
})
  
selectInput("I", label = "category_I:",
           choices = names(catI_sales))


dygraphs::renderDygraph({
  dygraph(catI_sales[[input$I]])
})
```